# How to hide scope buttons properly

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, ios12

Initial state:

[image: Initial state]

sb.showsScopeBar is set to false

searchBarShouldBeginEditing make the scope buttons appears when the search bar is activated:

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ sb: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        sb.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
        sb.scopeButtonTitles = scopeButtonTitles
}
```

[image]

Tapping the cancel button, hides the scope buttons properly and we are back to the original state.

N.B. *This is the default behaviour and our searchBarCancelButtonClicked is not doing anything apart from restoring the previous query text if necessary.*

[image: Initial state]

Now comes the annoying bits...

If I put

```
sb.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
```

in either searchBarShouldEndEditing or searchBarTextDidEndEditing, the cancel button goes away but the scope buttons just shrink:

[image]

Adding `sb.scopeButtonTitles = nil` makes the scope buttons go away but then the search bar doesn't resize :

[image]

Calling sb.sizeToFit() doesn't seem to help at all... using sb.showsScopeBar breaks the search bar UI completely.

Comment: is this possible to attach the project'

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution!

To simulate the behaviour of pressing the cancel button (hide the scope buttons and resize the search bar):

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ sb: UISearchBar) {
    sb.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    searchController?.isActive = false
}
```

We don't need to set sb.scopeButtonTitles to nil.

Comment: maybe it makes more sense to put it in `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`